# What are deprecated features in .NET?

Tags: .net

How can I search for total of new and deprecated features in .NET between each version? Features such as:

- Interfaces
- Classes
- Exceptions
- Fields
- Methods
- Constructors

What I'm looking for is a report similar to [20 Years Of Java Deprecation](https://www.azul.com/20-years-java-deprecation/).

Comment: Microsoft is reluctant to mark items obsolete. Thus, even if you can see which items are obsolete right now, there should be more than them. NDepend can be the tool to use and they have several blogs on analyzing what's new.

Comment: There seems to be a pretty complete list on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461502(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).